# Problem saving shared preferences in Android

Tags: android, variables, sharedpreferences

Right now I am trying to save a variable when i close the app and get the variable back when i open the app back up. I have no idea if I'm doing this right. My variable is called count and would like to save and restore it. Is this right? If so, why isn't it working? If not, what do i need to change? (i'm obviously using SharedPreferences)

```
protected void onPause(){
   super.onPause();


  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_COUNT, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("count", count);
  editor.commit();
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_COUNT, 0);
    count = settings.getInt("count", count);
}
```

Comment: "why isn't it working?" -> could you be more precise? Are you getting an error? Is your value incorrect? Have you run your debugger?

Comment: Well, the app loads fine, but does not save the variable.

Comment: Absolutely no error, but I got it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks right except make sure you have a constant:

```
public static final String PREFS_COUNT = "MyPrefsFile";
```

declared at the beginning of your activity. It's all right here in Google's documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Should work fine if you follow that exactly.

Comment: Ah, i see. i have forgotten to load the preferences in the "Oncreate bundle"...... Thanks

Comment: Funny that solved my problem, even I do not understand why, I used the call like: getSharedPreferences(MyClass.getSimpleName(), 0); that should be pretty constant...

Comment: The point is not that you need the static string, the point is that you need to be using a common preferences file across your application, correct?

Comment: My SharedPreferences were not working before, and now they are, after setting the file name as static final on the class. I guess that is indeed a requirement.